# Append single value to data frame stored in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, append

If the file exists, the value should be appended to the dataframe/ the file. In the left column I want to see the index, in the right column I want to see the according values. Currently, the data frame in the csv file looks like this after appending values several times: [No index printed, values in the wrong column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqJCK.png). What do I have to change to get index on the left side, value on the right side and a new row with the subsequent index when a new value is available? Really appreciate any help!

```
user_name = ("Tal")
number_of_used_guesses = 2
path = "/users/me/folder_name/"

filename = (user_name)+'.csv'

df = pd.DataFrame(number_of_used_guesses)

if os.path.exists(filename):
    append_write = 'a' # append if already exists
    df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
    
else:
    append_write = 'w' # make a new file if not
```